# (Solution verification) Compute the integral $\iint_{R}\frac{1}{(1+x+y)^2}dA $ if $R$ is the region bounded by lines $y=2x$,$x=2y$ and $x+y=6$

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, solution-verification

> Compute the integral
> $\iint_{R}\frac{1}{(1+x+y)^2}dA $ if $R$ is the region bounded by lines $y=2x$,$x=2y$ and $x+y=6$

Essentially I only need to know if I got the integration bounds correctly. I went ahead and solved this by first making a sketch to determine the bounds, from which I obtained that $0\leq x \leq 4$ and $\frac{x}{2} \leq y \leq 2x$, as can be seen by the following:
[image]

Therefore, the iterated integral should be something like the following:
$$\int_{0}^4 dx \int_{x/2}^{2x} \frac{1}{(1+x+y)^2}dy$$
which is easily integrated as following:
$$\int_{0}^4 dx \int_{x/2}^{2x} \frac{1}{(1+x+y)^2}dy=\int_{0}^4 \frac{2}{2+3x} -\frac{1}{1+3x}dx=\frac{2 \ln{14}-\ln{13}-\ln{2}}{3}$$
My main concern is that the $y$ bound should perhaps be something like $\frac{x}{2} \leq y \leq 4.$

As stated, I'm essentially only interested if I got the integration bounds correct. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your bounds are not correct. Considering the domain as [normal with respect to the x-axis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_integral#x-axis), you should split the integral as
$$\int_{x=0}^2 dx \int_{y=x/2}^{2x} \frac{1}{(1+x+y)^2}dy+\int_{x=2}^4 dx \int_{y=x/2}^{6-x} \frac{1}{(1+x+y)^2}dy$$

Comment: Thanks! Makes sense!